# PHP/MYSQL select single object returns col name instead of value

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why, but when I run this script, it's only displaying the `$row[0]` column and not any other columns I put in.

```
$mlsnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['mlsnum']);

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db('singleprop', $link);

$query = "SELECT 'MSTLISTPRC' FROM jos_mls WHERE MSTMLSNO = '".$mlsnum."';";

$return = mysql_query($query);

$result = mysql_fetch_array($return);

$price = $result['MSTLISTPRC'];

echo $price;
```

Instead of echoing the value of the column that meets the `WHERE` criteria, it echoes the column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the single quotes. They indicate a literal string.

```
SELECT MSTLISTPRC ...
```

> A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (“`'`”) or double quote (“`"`”) characters. Examples:
>
> `'a string'`
>
> `"another string"`

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

You also need to use an associative array in order to call the column name:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($return);
```

Also, please stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: When I do this, I don't get the value it should show, I only get `0`.  I can verify what the value should be through PHPmyAdmin and that the `$mlsnum` value queried is correct.

Comment: @tPlummer print_r($result); you will see why.

Comment: @tPlummer See my update. You need to use an associative array.

Comment: @Dagon - Did both of your suggestions.  I still get `0` on the `print_r()`.  I have not clue what's going on.  I've verified that everything is correct and I know what the result should be, it just keeps putting out `0`.

Comment: @tPlummer Add error handling. `$return = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Ok, so I got rid of `mysql_real_escape_string` and it works.  But this leaves my vulnerable to SQL injections, right?

Comment: try: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.\n<br />Query: " . $query . "<br />\nError: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error()); `

Comment: You should note that backticks ` are what can be used to enclose table/field names in mysql.

Comment: @Sammitch As mentioned below; they're not necessary unless escaping reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotes around 'MSTLISTPRC' = problem solved

Answer (score 0):

For selecting column you do not use quotes. We use "`" character

Comment: no. you only use backticks if your column name is a reserved word. otherwise they're just extra fluff.

Comment: Your right but it does no harm to always use backticks when your ot sure your column name is reserved or not

Comment: @MIIB Some people don't like extra fluff

Answer (score 0):

change 
    $query = "SELECT 'MSTLISTPRC' FROM jos_mls WHERE MSTMLSNO = '".$mlsnum."';";
to
    $query = "SELECT `MSTLISTPRC` FROM jos_mls WHERE MSTMLSNO = '".$mlsnum."';";